# How to restrict Flutter Voice Recognition to specific words only?

Tags: android, flutter, voice-recognition

I have a Flutter application for mathematic field. (targeted to android, ios, web?).

In a section, I need to get user voice continuously(max: 3mins) listening for a specific (pre-defined) words, without any interruption!
Each time the user says one of the specific words, the application should go to next step.

**Could you mention what you have done in that kind of situations, please?**
Or, what is your preferred solutions?

I have tried to use "speech_to_text: ^6.4.0" pub package, but it's not working continuously!

As shown in the code, the listenFor property didn't wait for 3 minutes!
It's just listening while the user is speaking, otherwise it will be stopped!

```
if (available) {
  setState(() {
    _isListening = true;
  });

  _speech.listen(
    onResult: (result) {
      setState(() {
        _text = result.recognizedWords;
      });
    },
    listenFor: const Duration(minutes: 3),
  );
}
```